# TypeError: _reactNativePushNotification.default.localNotificationSchedule is not a function while writing unit test

Tags: react-native, jestjs, enzyme, react-native-push-notification

I am not able to write unit test for the following code

```
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification'
import { timeZoneForNotification } from '../Assets/Constants/constants'
import firebase from 'react-native-firebase'
export const scheduleNotification = ({ 
    title = timeZoneForNotification.title, 
    message 
 },
  date
) => {
  PushNotification.localNotificationSchedule({ title, message, date })
}
```

Comment: Hi, @Sharad Did u get the solution?

Comment: Hi @Maheshvirus mock all methods of react-native-push-notification which your using

Comment: Did the mock but still didn't worked. Can you please share a mocking code if you have.

Comment: @Maheshvirus check my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the way to mock

```
jest.mock('react-native-push-notification', () => ({
  configure: jest.fn(),
  onRegister: jest.fn(),
  onNotification: jest.fn(),
  addEventListener: jest.fn(),
  requestPermissions: jest.fn()
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please add native code for notification module.

For reference:

https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-push-notification-ios#appdelegatem

Comment: looks like it is only for IOS , i am looking for Android

Comment: You have to write custom native bridge in android. There is no default functionality in react native